# Why my elasticsearch failed to build transportclient in JAVA API?

Tags: exception, elasticsearch, nullpointerexception, java

I have an simple code of elasticsearch in Java like this :

```
public class TryElastic {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    json.put("user","kimchy");
    json.put("postDate",new Date());
    json.put("message","trying out Elasticsearch");

    try {
        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();

        TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
        //client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    } catch (NoNodeAvailableException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("test");
}
```

}

It's very simple but I got an error in the following line :

```
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build();
```

It display error message like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.randomNodeName(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:198)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.finalizeSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:177)
at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:64)
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient$Builder.build(TransportClient.java:119)
at TryElastic.main(TryElastic.java:64)
```

So, can you give me suggestion, I've looking for the solution, and I can't find that. Is there any configuration that I've to implement? My elasticsearch server have ran correctly, It can perform index and get queries from command prompt. Thanks...

Comment: Which version of ES are you using? Do you happen to have a file named `names.txt` in your ES `config` folder? Can you show how you start the ES server process? A simple way to fix this is to set the `node.name` property in your `elasticsearch.yml` config file.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me. This is the version issue. Default port of TransportClient is 9300 and the code does not compile with Elasticsearch 2.0

*Use this*:

Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
      .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();

Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build()
      .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));

Refer: [Here's the link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-in-java-transportclient-nonodeavailableexception-none-of-the-configured-nodesare-available/34452/3)