# Error : Uncaught error from thread [studying-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, intellij-idea, jvm

i want to read data from elasticsearch and then the result would be API.

my **build.sbt**

```
name := "studying"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
resolvers += "spray nightlies repo" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Spray repository" at "http://repo.spray.io",
  "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-json_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-can_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-client_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-testkit_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-routing_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-http_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-httpx_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-util_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-can_2.10" % "1.3.2"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" % "elastic4s-streams_2.10" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-mapper-attachments" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote_2.10" % "2.3.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j_2.10" % "2.3.7"
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" % "lift-json_2.9.1" % "2.6.3"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7"
```

**error**

```
[ERROR] [11/04/2016 09:25:20.662] [studying-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [ActorSystem(studying)] Uncaught error from thread [studying-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
```

**another references**
[Uncaught error from default dispatcher causes fatal error with JavaTestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120369/uncaught-error-from-default-dispatcher-causes-fatal-error-with-javatestkit)
[Uncaught fatal error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down ActorSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418770/uncaught-fatal-error-from-thread-default-akka-actor-default-dispatcher-5-shutt)
[Why my elasticsearch failed to build transportclient in JAVA API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532411/why-my-elasticsearch-failed-to-build-transportclient-in-java-api)
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-in-java-transportclient-nonodeavailableexception-none-of-the-configured-nodesare-available/34452
[ElasticSearch 2.0 Transport Client - No Node Available exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522581/elasticsearch-2-0-transport-client-no-node-available-exception)

i was following 5 instructions above, but the error **still same**. any idea or references or link or clue?

im using SDK : 2.10.5, intellij idea : 2016.1

thanks anyway!

**EDIT 1** : Typo title

Comment: Try to find _Guava_ library with 17.0 version or early in your project. In IntelliJ open project structure and on `External Libraries`. If you have it let me know.

Comment: hello mr @AntonDozortsev, im using sbt. how can i find **guava library**? thanks

Comment: As I said in comment bellow. In IntelliJ open project structure and in expanded External Libraries section you can see all you dependencies.

Comment: ok, i found **guava library 18.0**. and then?

Comment: Only with this version ? Look carefully because usually `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` indicate about version collision

Comment: yes only version 18.0.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add a dependency for Guava 18.0 or better in your built.sbt file.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: @SunBright Explicitly means `libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "19.0"`